# Continuously writing data from different classes to a text file

Tags: java, android

I have 3 different classes, 1 that monitors the accelerometer data, 1 that tracks GPS and one to write to a file.

I am using this code to write to the file in the accel and GPS class:

GPS

`file.write(Latitude + "," + Longitude);`

Accel

`file.write(sensorEvent.values[0] + ", " + sensorEvent.values[1] + ", " + sensorEvent.values[2]);`

Which goes to the write method in the file class;

```
public void write(String message) {
    try {
        if (out == null) {
            FileWriter datawriter = new FileWriter(file);
            out = new BufferedWriter(datawriter);
        }
        if (file.exists()) {
            out.append(message);
            out.flush();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "fail to write file");
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that its only writing one line with the accel values in it and no GPS.

How do I write the a line that contains both accel and GPS values, and to keep writing those values to the same file.

Answer (score 4):

new FileWiriter(file) creates a new empty file, so you only get the last line written, all previous lines were removed. You should add the second parameter append=true to the FileWriter constructor

```
FileWriter datawriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could concat the output of both classes to one string and pass that to your write function:

```
myString = yourGpsClassExecute
myString += yourAccelExecute
write(myString)
```

Comment: As Chuidiang posted as I wrote this, this will create only the one line at a time, with both values. For a running log, you would also implement Chuidiang's response

Comment: I've created the MyString just as you have, but when I try it in the second class the "+=" gives a syntax error that it should only be "=".

Comment: Try myString = myString + (or 'myString . ' or whatever character represents concatenation for you) yourAccelExecute

Comment: Have tried that. `String toWrite = accel.concat(GPS);` in the accel class, but the gps throws the error. I've tried `String GPS = String GPSExample.class.` but there is no getString method that would return the GPS string. I've set them to public to see if that would make a difference but none.

Comment: I had assumed both classes were returning the data you wanted as a string. If one (or both) are printing to screen from their own execution, you would need to either alter/extend the class to return the value properly, or capture your system's output buffer during that class's execution